Saving ZSH history across SSH sessions
Is it possible to keep zsh history consistent across SSH sessions to the same machine?
To explain further, let's say I opened an SSH session to another computer, ran mkdir test-dir/, and exited the session. I would like to later SSH into the same server in a new terminal session, and be able to see mkdir test-dir/ when I run history or invoke reverse-i-search.
I understand potential limitations in keeping track of this history across sessions, but maybe it's possible with some kind of plugin.

Isn't this the way it normally works? Granted, I'm not that familiar with zsh, but I do know bash, and this is exactly what bash does, and from what I've heard I don't think history is one of the things that differs that much between the two.

To save history between sessions, you primarily need to set a few variables for history size in your ~/.zshrc. For example.
HISTSIZE=10000
HISTFILE=~/.zshistory
SAVEHIST=8000

Avoid using export with these. That can be especially annoying when something exports smaller sizes, sometimes from a bash setup causing history to get truncated.
There are many history related options, set with setopt and documented in zshoptions(1) to do things like sharing history between concurrent sessions and to affect handling of duplicate commands.
